# Meaning of "Lars kam sich unendlich verlassen vor"

Tags: meaning, translation, verb, sentence-structure, reflexive

I'm reading *Kleiner Eisbär, wohin fährst du?* von Hans de Beer but I'm puzzled by this sentence:

> Lars kam sich unendlich verlassen vor.

If *verlassen* is a reflexive verb as the word *sich* suggests, then the sentence means Lars depends on his father. But if *verlassen* is an adjective then the sentence appears to read as "Lars came himself endlessly deserted before." I can't figure out how the words *sich* and *vor* function in this sentence.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Verlassen** is an adjective here. The predicate is **vorkommen**. The closest translation keeping the structure of the sentence is

> Lars seemed endlessly deserted to himself.

while in an English text you would probably just say

> Lars felt endlessly deserted.

**Vorkommen** is not necessarily reflexive, it can be used in this sense with any kind of indirect object, e.g.

> Die Situation kam mir/dir/dem Mann seltsam vor.

Comment: Ah! I did not realize that vor was a separable verb prefix in this sentence.

Answer (score 6):

In this sentence, **verlassen** is a participle, "left alone".

**sich vorkommen** can be translated as "feel like".